# How do I use R to download tabular data for Census 2000 blocks?

Tags: r, tidycensus

Attempting to use tidycensus package to download data.

As I read it, [tidycensus](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidycensus/tidycensus.pdf) supports blocks for 2000. Tract works, block group works, blocks fail

```
library(tidycensus)
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#------Get Decennial Census Data
ut2000tract <- get_decennial(geography = "tract", variables = "P001001", 
year = 2000, sumfile = "sf1", key = mykey, state = "49", county = "035", 
geometry = FALSE)
ut2000BG <- get_decennial(geography = "block group", variables = 
"P001001", year = 2000, sumfile = "sf1",
key = mykey, state = "49", county = "035", geometry = FALSE)
ut2000block <- get_decennial(geography = "block", variables = "P001001", 
year = 2000, sumfile = "sf1", key = mykey, state = "49", county = "035", 
geometry = FALSE)
```

Generating the following error:

> [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidycensus/tidycensus.pdf) "Checking SF3 API for data..." [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidycensus/tidycensus.pdf) "Client error Bad Request
>   Client error: (400) Bad Request" Error in
>   stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern,
>   fix_replacement(replacement),  :    argument `str` should be a
>   character vector (or an object coercible to) Error in
>   gather.default(., key = variable, value = value, -GEOID, -NAME) :
>   object 'NAME' not found

I know block should be a valid geometry; I just want a count of population/block, which is in the [Census 2000 SF1 file](https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?pid=DEC_10_SF1_P1&prodType=table). Not sure why 
tidycensus is not working. Pulling data for 2010 seems to work. But not 2000.

[totalcensus](https://github.com/GL-Li/totalcensus) doesn't cover Census 2000

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109241/r-tidycensus-download-all-block-groups

Comment: Possible duplicate of [r tidycensus download all block groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109241/r-tidycensus-download-all-block-groups)

Comment: I wish. It may just be making a very basic error. But I can't figure out what.

Comment: Can you share more/all/a short version of your code so that we can try it out ourselves?

Comment: Apart from some library loads, the above is all of it. Tract works, block group works, block fails.

Comment: If the packages are necessary for the code to work, please do share which library loads. Also what is the "..." at the end of the first chunk of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161568/discussion-between-jesstme-and-mox).

Comment: https://github.com/walkerke/tidycensus/issues/13

Comment: Remember that not all data is available at the block level.

Comment: Checked; the variable I'm using is a simple count of population, available for all levels of geography.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of tidycensus; I answered this on the GitHub issues page (https://github.com/walkerke/tidycensus/issues/51) but I'll cross-post here.

This is due to a limitation of the Census API; block data for 2000 are only available by Census tract within counties in the API, and I don't have functionality in the package to handle this at the moment. I've added a new error message in the package to explain this.  My recommended alternatives:

- Use NHGIS (http://www.nhgis.org) to download the data and the ipumsr package (https://github.com/mnpopcenter/ipumsr) which provides an excellent new interface to use it in R.
- Use the censusapi package (https://github.com/hrecht/censusapi) which lets you construct any Census API query you want.  If you were to generate a vector of tract IDs for your desired county, you could likely use purrr's `map_df()` to iterate through these IDs and get the output you need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109241/r-tidycensus-download-all-block-groups/47683019?noredirect=1#comment85087712_47683019